# loading env variables in react app using vite

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables, vite

I´ve been through all the docs from vite, react.js and dev blogs, but I'm not getting it to work

I have a .env file which contains the following

```
VITE_API_KEY = XXX
```

inside my firebase.js file I'm loading it like :

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: import.meta.env.API_KEY,
   .....
   .....
}
// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

but it appears as **null**, I've restarted the dev server, reinstalled node_modules (just in case) changed var prefixes to REACT_APP_XX, tried using process.env.XX global object, basically gone through all different ways to read vars from a .env file in react

I´ve also tried to clog it from a component but it has the same result

any suggestions/methods to solve this problem?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

finally solved this problem,
the thing was that:

```
import.meta.env.VITE_XX
```

this env variable are statically replaced during production, not development, at least in my case I solved this by checking the mode by doing

```
 if(import.meta.env.MODE === "development"){
//use dev keys
}
else{
//use .env variables
}
```

when in production mode

```
import.meta.env.VITE_XX
```

variables will load correctly, so you can add them as env variables in your deployment service and it will work fine. I've tested it with vercel and it worked

Comment: Where did you put this please ?

Comment: @AbdulhameedMustapha you can define your env variables in a **.env** file then you can grab their values as described above

Comment: I'm using import.meta.env.VITE_XX in both production and developement and it works in development and doesn't work in production with Vercel.

Answer (score 40):

The environment variable name used in code must match the name set in the `.env` file:

```js
// .env
VITE_API_KEY=abcd1234
```

```
// firebase.js
const firebaseConfig = {      
  apiKey: import.meta.env.VITE_API_KEY,
  ⋮
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-using-dotenv?file=src/App.jsx)

Relevant documentation can be found in the [Vite Env variables](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode#env-files) docs

Comment: Not going the lie, the emojis are 10/10

Answer (score 21):

It works if all variables start with VITE_

Answer (score 3):

By default .env key should be placed in the "root" folder. That means by default it should be placed outside of "src" folder. **OR** you can define "envDir" in you *vite.config.js*

```
  export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    envDir: './src/envs',
```

See: https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options#envdir

Comment: thanks, this was frustrating but turned out to be my issue. ⭐ to you

Answer (score 0):

Simple logic use **`VITE_`** for the .env variables to work.

Then you can use it as `import.meta.env.VITE_`

---

Example:

```
.env file => `VITE_ANY_KEY` 

.jsx/tsx file => import.meta.env.VITE_ANY_KEY
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use defineConfig like this :

```
 import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite';

export default ({ mode }) => {
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), '');

  return defineConfig({
    base: env.VITE_ROUTER_BASE_URL || '/',
    define: {
      'process.env': env,
    },
}
```

This worked for me to use

> 'process.env': env,

Answer (score 0):

**Try removing quotes from the values of keys in the .env file; it might resolve the issue.**

API_KEY="your_api_key"

API_KEY=your_api_key